# iOS multitasking not supported

Tags: ios, background, multitasking

Hopefully a simple question, but I don't have an iOS3 / device multitasking is not supported on.

My app is now set to run in the background (plays audio), I have an animation that runs and I terminate that through applicationDidEnterBackground.

I want my app to exit if multitasking is not supported. I have code in place to detect multitasking capabilities:

```
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
    backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;

if (backgroundSupported == NO) {
    NSLog(@"Multitasking not supported");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Multitasking supported");
}
```

My question is.... how can I kill the app from inside the else statement above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would work: exit(0)

This is also possible, [[NSThread mainThread] exit], and this is probably a nicer way to do so, stay with Objective-C if you can my friend.